# HTML Button Element not working on Chrome IOS while using Canvas element

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-chrome, button, html5-canvas

I face an issue with a button element to download an image generated by the Canvas element the function working on all devices except the following Chrome ios on iPhone and Ipad. meanwhile, it is working on Chrome on Android and desktops normally.

**Here is a link to the [project](https://maee.vercel.app/)**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
var downloadBtn = document.getElementById("download-btn");

var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/qM9BjSK/maee.png";
image.onload = function() {
  drawImage();
};

function drawImage() {
  // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "60px Cairo";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";

  ctx.fillText(nameInput.value, 750, 975);
}

nameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
  drawImage();
});

downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", function downladDrw() {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // Set the image data as the link URL
  link.download = "Congrates - " + nameInput.value; // Set the desired file name
  link.click();
});
```

```css
/*
* Prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io
* PostCSS: v8.4.14,
* Autoprefixer: v10.4.7
* Browsers: last 4 version
*/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

img,
picture,
video,
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: var(--brand_color_five--);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("https://maee.gov.sa/branding/images/SVG/pater.svg");
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* margin-top: 2rem; */
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.secret-holder {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.card {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer p {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  canvas {
    width: 970px;
    height: 970px;
  }
}


/* Large */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  canvas {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 698px) {
  canvas {
    width: 400px !important;
    height: 400px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>MAEE Eid Mubarak</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Eid Mubarak</h1>
    <div class="card">
      <label dir="rtl">
          <input
            class="m-2 form-control"
            id="name"
            type="text"
            required
            placeholder="اكتب اسمك هنا "
            dir="rtl" />
        </label>
      <button id="download-btn" type="button" onclick="" class="btn btn-md btn-primary m-2" dir="rtl">
          اضغط للتحميل
        </button>

      <canvas id="canvas" height="1500px" width="1500px"></canvas>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>Powered by G-Media &nbsp; &nbsp; copyrights &copy; MAEE.com</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

if you could help I will be appreciated it.

Regards, Hossam

I tried to test it on other ios devices but the same result download button not working.

I tried to test it on the below mobile browser to check if it is only with Chrome for ios only or if the issue is in the code.

- Chrome Ios (Private mode): not working.
- Firefox Ios normal mode and (Private mode): not working.
- Opera mobile Ios normal mode and (Private mode): not working.
- Edge mobile Ios normal mode and (Private mode): not working.
- Working fine with safari.